# Unable to login to Minio Console POST to :9000

Tags: kubernetes, minio, k3s, k0s

I recently deployed Minio stand-alone on a K0s pod. I can successfully use mc on my laptop to authenticate and create a bucket on my pod’s ip:9000.

But when I try to access the web console and login I get a POST error to ip:9000 and I am unable to login.

Would anyone know what’s causing this?

Answer (score 3):

I've just started a minio container to verify this and it fact there are two ports you need to publish which are `9000` and `9001`.

You can reach the admin console on port `9001` and the API on port `9000`, hence your `mc` command which targets port `9000` works but trying to login on port `9000` fails.

[image: MinIO admin console on port 9001]

### Edit

Now that I understand the problem better thanks to your comments I've tested on my Docker what happens when you login. And in fact there is a `POST` request happening when clicking on `Login` but it's not going to port `9001` not `9000`, so it seems the your webconsole somehow issues request to the wrong port.

Here a screenshot of the Network tab in my DevTools showing the request that's being issued when I press Login.
[image: Chrome Dev Tools: Login request]

I've copied the `curl` for this request from the DevTool and added the `-i` flag so you can see the HTTP response code. You could try this with your appropriate `accessKey` and `secretKey` of course.

```sh
curl -i 'http://localhost:9001/api/v1/login'   -H 'Connection: keep-alive'   -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.83 Safari/537.36'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -H 'Accept: */*'   -H 'Sec-GPC: 1'   -H 'Origin: http://localhost:9001'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors'   -H 'Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty'   -H 'Referer: http://localhost:9001/login'   -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9'   -H 'Cookie: PGADMIN_LANGUAGE=en'   --data-raw '{"accessKey":"minio-root-user","secretKey":"minio-root-password"}'   --compressed
```

Expected result:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: MinIO Console
Set-Cookie: token=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; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 26 Mar 2022 13:23:34 GMT; Max-Age=3600; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
Date: Sat, 26 Mar 2022 12:23:34 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: I already am accessing the admin console on 9001. When I click login with the username and password I get a error. “POST to ip:9000 failed”

Comment: Current I have port 9000 and 9001 open on the pod and have 9001 forward to port 80. 

The error I get is “ Post "http://192.168.4.73:9000/": dial tcp 192.168.4.73:9000: i/o timeout”

Comment: Which container images are you using? `bitnami/minio` or `minio/minio`? Might be some missing config there. Certainly looks like some problem with routing. Does it work without the forward?

Comment: I am using minio/minio. let me modify the svc to just use 9001 and 9000 and get back to you.

Comment: Just modified my ports to use 9001 and 9000 and still same issue

Comment: Try the `curl` command from above (with keys/ IP adjusted of course) to port `9001`. That should work. If it does you would then just need to figure out why your minio tries to connect to port `9000` and not `9001`.